# Creating Sub-Blocks Within Existing Polygon using ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I am new to ArcGIS Desktop.

I'm trying to create some sub-blocks within a block. The idea is to divide the block to sub-blocks which follow natural features like river/stream, block's boundary, topography etc. And, the neighbouring sub-blocks should share the boundary. I don't how to make it right, snapping is not the right choice for me when tracing the stream and border especially on location with lot of curve.

Could someone suggest the best way to make it done?

I posted some photos just to share what I try to do.

[image: Base layer: contour, stream & block]

[image: Needed result but for the whole block]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like what you are after are some sort of slope facets.  This is best done as a raster operation. Doing it as a raster operation will ensure that there are no topology issues with neighboring "blocks" not lining up properly.  Here is a proposed workflow:

1. Decide which variables you'd like to go into determining the facets.  Aspect is the one that comes to my mind, but you might also want to consider slope.
2. Use the reclassify tool to convert aspect or slope into discrete classes.
3. Use the Combine tool to put these different layers together.
4. Convert the output from the combine tool to polygons.  Choose NOT to generalize.
5. You'll end up with some smaller polygons that you may want to merge into larger neighbors.  Sort the attribute table.  You can use the Eliminate tool to automate the selection or if there are few enough of them just manually merge them into the neighboring polygon of your choice in an edit session.

Comment: My objective is to create smaller blocks between 400-700 ha within that polygon, and to make the boundary easier to identify on the field, I decided to make the sub-blocks boundary either the stream or ridge. Is your recommendation suitable for my objective? Thank you

Comment: Hi Max. The reclassify step should determine the resolution. More classes means smaller polygons generally. You may have to try different sizes to get a solution that you like best.